# Rails - link name with umlauts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8, diacritics

I'm facing a quite little problem. 
In my view.html.erb, I'm using words with German umlauts (ä, ö, ü..). Of course it's not working, to write äöü in the html.erb like this, I need to write the normal HTML-umlauts-codes (`&uuml;`) so the umlauts will be viewed in browser. This is working quite well, but it's not working in the link name as you can see in this picture: http://img7.imagebanana.com/img/540vnz2y/umlaut.PNG

This is the code I'm using right now:
`<p>  <%= link_to "zur&Uuml;ck", :controller => "employees", :action => "index" %>`

does anybody know how to manage it that I can also use umlauts in link-names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails 3 automatically escapes strings, use `html_safe` to avoid escaping.

```
<%= link_to "&Uuml;bersicht".html_safe , :controller => "employees", :action => "show", :id => @employee %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just write like this:

`<%= link_to "äöü", something_url %>`

I've got in all of my views utf8 coding and I can easily use Polish diacritics in link_to methods.

Comment: Hm, it's not working with German umlauts. I get a wrongEncodingError.

Comment: My bad, I thought that is no difference between Polish, Swedish and German diacritics encoded in utf8

Comment: Yeah, that would be logical :D Discrimination!

Comment: It works for me, BUT! If you use a special font (@font-face) there may be problems displaying the umlauts in that font.